# JavaScript- storing the mouse X and Y positions in variables, and continuously updating them as the mouse is moved

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, coordinates, kineticjs, mousemove

I have an HTML5 canvas which is displaying a number of images. Some of these images are draggable, and some are not. I've added the draggable functionality using a local copy of the KineticJS library (I'm using a local copy since there are one or two functions I wanted to edit slightly).

What I'm looking to do at the moment, is create a couple of JS variables to store the current location of the cursor whenever it is 'on' the canvas. The reason I want to be able to do this, is so that I can detect where the cursor is when the user is dragging one of the draggable images, and check whether or not they have dragged it to the correct location.

I've written the following function to do this:

```
function getMousePosition(mouseX, mouseY){
    mouseX = e.clientX;
    mouseY = e.clientY;
    console.log("mouseX = " + mouseX);
    console.log("mouseY = " + mouseY);
}
```

and I'm calling this function from within the KineticJS `_mousemove` function, so that this function now looks like this:

```
_mousemove: function(evt) {
    this._setUserPosition(evt);
    var dd = Kinetic.DD;
    var obj = this.getIntersection(this.getUserPosition());
    getMousePostion(mouseX, mouseY);

    if(obj) {
        var shape = obj.shape;
        if(shape) {
            if((!dd || !dd.moving) && obj.pixel[3] === 255 && (!this.targetShape || this.targetShape._id !== shape._id)) {
                if(this.targetShape) {
                    this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseout', evt, shape);
                    this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseleave', evt, shape);
                }
                shape._handleEvent('mouseover', evt, this.targetShape);
                shape._handleEvent('mouseenter', evt, this.targetShape);
                this.targetShape = shape;
            }
            else {
                shape._handleEvent('mousemove', evt);
            }
        }
    }
    /*
     * if no shape was detected, clear target shape and try
     * to run mouseout from previous target shape
     */
    else if(this.targetShape && (!dd || !dd.moving)) {
        this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseout', evt);
        this.targetShape._handleEvent('mouseleave', evt);
        this.targetShape = null;
    }

    // start drag and drop
    if(dd) {
        dd._startDrag(evt);
    }
}
```

The problem I'm having, is that when I view my page in a browser, and move the cursor over the canvas, I get the Firebug console error: "getMousePostion is not defined" with every movement of the cursor. Some of these errors only say that, and some of them have a small '+' next to them.

If I expand one of the errors that has a '+' next to it, I get the following additional information:

```
_mousemove()kinetic.js (line 3443)
evt = mousemove clientX=15, clientY=229
(?)()kinetic.js (line 3417)
evt = mousemove clientX=15, clientY=229
```

Each error that is expandable show different figures for `clientX` and `clientY`, which shows that my function clearly is getting the x & y coordinates of the cursor as it moves around the canvas. So what I'm wondering is why I'm getting the errors telling me that `getMousePosition` is not defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are trying to get properties of an object that doesn't exist, ie `e`. Instead of passing `mouseX` and `mouseY` to the function, you should be passing and event object.

```
//you're passing parameters that don't exist in _mousemove
function getMousePosition(mouseX, mouseY){
    mouseX = e.clientX; //and trying to use e, which doesn't exist
    mouseY = e.clientY;
    //also passed parameters aren't meant to be used as local variables like this
    console.log("mouseX = " + mouseX);
    console.log("mouseY = " + mouseY);
}
```

Change the parameter you pass to be an event object, and create `mouseX` and `mouseY` as local variables, and it should work. Another VERY big problem is that in `_mousemove` you are calling the function `getMousePostion`. Notice the spelling. You forgot an 'i'.

```
function getMousePosition(e){
    var mouseX = e.clientX;
    var mouseY = e.clientY;
    console.log("mouseX = " + mouseX);
    console.log("mouseY = " + mouseY);
}

_mousemove: function(evt) {
    ...
    getMousePosition(evt);
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply- I gave that I go, but I'm still getting exactly the same errors in the console. I don't know if it's worth mentioning that the `getMousePosition` function has been defined in my index.html page. The kinetic.js file has been included in my HTML file, so I would have thought that calling a function defined in the HTML file from the JS file would be Ok... Unless there is something I need to do to make the script inside the HTML visible to the script outside the HTML?

Comment: I don't think it would affect it, as long as `_mousemove` isn't being called until after the whole page is loaded. Did you get my edit when you tried the changes? The spelling of `getMousePosition` in `_mousemove` is actual reason it's saying the function is undefined. The rest of the changes are just things you're going to run into once you fix the spelling.

Comment: Ah brilliant! Thanks- I completely missed the typo!

Comment: No problem. I actually missed it until I was completely done typing up the answer haha